# Clustering a single binary variable?

Tags: clustering

I am trying to design a study which will involve asking people to watch videos and then stop them at points that they think relevant (looking for specific behaviours). The idea is to see if people stop the video at the same time - I’m struggling to think how I can add some statistical analysis to this? I thought a cluster analysis but as the data will be largely binary (ie I will have each second of the video with a stop / not stop identifier) I’m not sure what I can do?

Comment: The content of your question is not very related with the title. It's not easy to come up with the right title, but if you provide more information about your problem, especially about the data you have available it might be easier to adjust it to attract more attention by people to answer!

Comment: You’re trying to cluster the *time stamps* of when people stopped the video. The time stamp isn’t binary.

Comment: Is stopping different than pausing? In other words, can a user stop multiple times in a video?

Comment: Sorry, ‘time stamps’ was just my clumsy wording. Participants will watch the video from start to end, during watching they will indicate points where they think they have seen a specific behaviour. What I want to capture is whether participants all stop at the same time points. In my mind the data would be a timeline of the video second by second and for each participant there will be notation to say they stopped… so basically if they watch 6 seconds of video and stop at second 5 it would be 0,0,0,0,1,0 with the 1 = stop

Comment: This elaboration doesn’t seem to meaningfully change my initial suggestion. Apply clustering for each time stamp corresponding to when the video is stopped/paused.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) on the time of stoppage.

You'll see something like YouTube videos show these days:

[image]

The grey bell shaped bumps on the image are the representation of frequency at which people jump into a point in the video.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with clustering using one binary variable in your case.

You could do a time-to-event analysis (aka survival analysis) to investigate the rate at which people stop the video. If you have some information about this people, such as sex or other characteristics, you can use a Cox Proportional Hazard model (that allows the inclusion of covariates) to study the effects of these characteristics on rate of these stops. You can also use Kaplan-Meier curves to investigate how a categorical variable influences the rate of stopping.

Even more simple, you could disregard the time and run a logistic regression using the covariates.

You can also look from another perspective. Imagine that you can divide the video in different parts based on some characteristics, for example the first part is introduction, the second part shows a lot of nature and so on (I am just imagining now). Then you can compare the characteristics of groups of subjects based on the section of video they stopped at.

This is not easy though, you might use some help from someone with experience in data analysis, if possible!

Comment: "*You cannot do clustering if you only have one variable.*" That isn't accurate *per se*.

Comment: Gotcha, I changed it.